# How many token get for one Wei?

Tags: solidity

How to calculate the number of tokens to be sent out for an incoming transaction of 1ETH. Assume my value for token is `0.80 USD`?

```
Token Price : 0.80 USD 
Value       : 0.0016940 ETH == 1694000000000000 WEI
```

Then i have calculated like this

```
uint256 public rate = 5.02373716 * (10 ** 8);

Where 5.02373716 = 1 / 1694000000000000
```